# Casting Qt5 QHelpEngine need obsolete casting

Tags: qt5

I am attempting to install a help browser starting from

http://www.walletfox.com/course/qhelpengineexample.php

For the line

```
tWidget->addTab(helpEngine->contentWidget(), tr("Contents"));
```

I receive error message

```
no known conversion from QHelpIndexWidget* to QWidget*
```

and really, if I make explicite casting with

```
tWidget->addTab((QWidget*)helpEngine->contentWidget(), tr("Contents"));
```

the program compiles and runs fine. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to `#include <QHelpIndexWidget>`.

Then the compiler can't deduct that a `QHelpIndexWidget` inherits from `QWidget`.

If you would try to access the `QHelpIndexWidget*`, like e.g.

```
qDebug() << helpEngine->indexWidget()->objectName();
```

without the `include`, you would get the better compiler error "QHelpIndexWidget is of incomplete type" or similar, which means that the type is forward declared, but the complete declaration is not accessible.

Additionally, I would suggest avoiding c-style casts and use `static_cast<TYPE>(var)` instead.